# make code run on every mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

This slideshow code works great but runs only once on first mouseover; how should I fix it to make it run on every mouseover (when completed)?

```
function slideImages(slider){ // slider is the element
  var $active = $('.active', slider); // search for .active in this element
  var $next = ($('.active', slider).next().length > 0) ? $('.active', slider).next() : $('img:first', slider);
  $next.css('z-index',2);
  $active.css('z-index',1);
  $next.animate({left:0},"fast",function(){

          $next.addClass('active');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.portfolio_slider').on('mouseover', function(){
    var _this = this; // save it for other context
    setInterval(function(){
        slideImages(_this);
    }, 400);
    $(this).off('mouseover');
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="portfolio_slider" style="float:left"> 
    <a id="by2" href="works.html"><img class="active" src="1.jpg" width="100" height="170">
        <img src="2.jpg" width="100" height="170">
        <img src="3.jpg" width="100" height="170">
        <img src="5.jpg" width="100" height="170">
        <img src="6.jpg" width="100" height="170">
        <img src="1.jpg" width="100" height="170">
        <p class="MAIN_TEXT">main</p>
        <p class="small_TEXT">small</p>
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: try removing $(this).off('mouseover');

Comment: Removing that is not enough.

Comment: @Abdulla Chozhimadathil, that's what I was already suggested, but still runs only once, I don't know why

Comment: @dari , what about the answer by mplungjan

Comment: @Abdulla Chozhimadathil, sorry, I replayed him

Comment: Please update your question instead of pasting html into comments. What is the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each slider a unique ID then try something like this

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/g4yqmc0k/) based on whatever you have given me so far.

```
var sliders = {};

function slideImages($slider) { // slider is the element
    var $active = $('.active', $slider); // search for .active in this element
    var last = $('.active', $slider).index() == sliders[$slider.id].max;
    $next = $('.active', $slider).next();
    if (last) {
        $next = $('img:first', $slider);
        $slider.find("img").first().addClass('active');
        $slider.on('mouseover', init);
        clearInterval(sliders[$slider.id].tId);
    }    
    $active.removeClass("active");
    $next.css('z-index', 2);
    $active.css('z-index', 1);
    $next.animate({
      left: 0
    }, "fast", function () {
        $next.addClass('active');
    });
}

function init() {
    var $this = $(this); // save it for other context
    sliders[$this.id] = {
        "max" :$this.find("img").length,
        "tId":setInterval(function () {
          slideImages($this);
        }, 400)
    };
    $this.off('mouseover');
}
$(function () {
    $('.portfolio_slider').on('mouseover', init);
});
```

Comment: I think I should re-run this when completed with last image, but I don't know how! $('.portfolio_slider').on('mouseover', function(){
    var _this = this; // save it for other context
    setInterval(function(){
        slideImages(_this);
    }, 400);
    $(this).off('mouseover');

});

Comment: the second choice makes slide show running on mouse over, stops on mouseout e starts again if I mouseover again, but still once only

Comment: user should see a complete slideshow on every mouseover event; if cycle is running, mouseover/out should not have any influence on slideshow, exactly as happens with my code, but with my code cycle runs only once. please note that there are multiple slideshows; could it be due to css code? .portfolio_slider{position:relative; width:100px; height:250px; overflow:hidden;}
.portfolio_slider img{position:absolute;left:100px;}
.portfolio_slider img.active{left:0}

Comment: somehow I'm still missing something; can't make this run once at least

Comment: not yet...HTML:<div class="portfolio_slider" style="float:left"> 
    <a id="by2" href="works.html"><img class="active" src="1.jpg" width="100" height="170">
    <img src="2.jpg" width="100" height="170">
    <img src="3.jpg" width="100" height="170">
    <img src="5.jpg" width="100" height="170">
    <img src="6.jpg" width="100" height="170">
    <img src="1.jpg" width="100" height="170">
    <p class="MAIN_TEXT">main</p>
    <p class="small_TEXT">small</p></a>
 </div>

Comment: still runs once, doesn't it?

Comment: Ok, Almost there. You can figure out the reason it slows on the first